# Windows store app using Javascript - How do I add event listener in html

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

In a Windows store app using Javascript, I have a listview defined in the html.

```
<div id ="menuListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
          itemDataSource: viewModel.items.dataSource,
          itemTemplate: menuItemTemplate,
          layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}"></div>
```

I could define a click event handler in Javascript something like this:

```
menuListView.addEventListener("selectionchanged", clickEventHandler, false);
```

But since, I'm trying to use the MVVM pattern, I would like to put this piece of code in the html view and let a viewmodel handle the click event. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full NVVM functionality in your WinJS app I would recommend using a framework like http://knockoutjs.com

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try something like this if you are keep to declare an event handler in HTML view :

```
"<button id="button1" onselectionchange="clickEventHandler(event)">An HTML button</button>"
```

Hope this helps :)